# MySQL - get users and their orders data from two tables correctly

Tags: mysql

I have users and orders tables with this structure (simplified for question):

**USERS**

userid

ownerid (user owner id, like main user)

company

**ORDERS**

id

date (order placed date)

user_id

total

I need to get all users related to one owner (ownerid, let's say 52 for example) who placed orders within selected period, as array with some fields (see in query). Unfortunately my request give ONE (not array) and not current result (sometimes even null in all fields). This is my request:

```
SELECT
  ei_users.userid as id,
  ei_users.company as company,
  ei_users.city as city,
  ei_users.user_type as user_type,
  ei_users.registered as registered,
  count(ei_orders.id) AS orders,
  sum(ei_orders.total) AS revenue
FROM
 ei_orders,
 ei_users
WHERE
 ei_users.userid = ei_orders.user_id 
 && ei_users.ownerid = 52 
 && DATE_FORMAT(ei_orders.date, "%b") = "Apr" 
 && DATE_FORMAT(ei_orders.date, "%Y") = "2019"
```

Please let me know what is wrong with my request and why I does not get array with results?

I found my mistake, I forgot to add **GROUP BY ei_users.userid** at the end:

```
SELECT
  ei_users.userid as id,
  ei_users.company as company,
  ei_users.city as city,
  ei_users.user_type as user_type,
  ei_users.registered as registered,
  count(ei_orders.id) AS orders,
  sum(ei_orders.total) AS revenue
FROM
 ei_orders,
 ei_users
WHERE
 ei_users.userid = ei_orders.user_id 
 && ei_users.ownerid = 52 
 && DATE_FORMAT(ei_orders.date, "%b") = "Apr" 
 && DATE_FORMAT(ei_orders.date, "%Y") = "2019"
GROUP BY ei_users.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I forgot to add at the end:

```
GROUP BY ei_users.userid
```